# Hibernate Annoration: how to get the bean of class annotated as @Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am writing a persistence layer code using hibernate.

I have soem DAO classes which I used to annotated as @Component.

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage;

@Component
class MyDAO {
}
```

I use component scan in my Spring configuration like this:

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.mypackage"/>
```

If I do so, a bean with id "myDAO" is created. However, I was told that it is better to use @Repository as it is a persistence layer code.

But after I replaced @Component with @Repository, the beans a not automatically created.

My questions are that: What is the difference between these two annodations? How can I create bean with auto scan and using @Repository? If I keep using @Component, will that work?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@Repository beans are eligible for persistence exception translation and the should be loaded at runtime.  This is what you want to use for your DAO layer.

@Component was added to Spring later and just means that the annontated class is a "spring bean" and will be loaded with during a component scan.

Generic DAOs don't mesh well with component scanning. This makes sense if you think about it - you need to be able to define multiple instances of this class, differing by the class passed into the constructor only. The class itself isn't capable of being autowired, so Spring can't do anything with it.

For this part, your best bet is to just define the repo instances in XML. If you're really determined to use component-scanning, you'll have to subclass the Generic DAO and provide a default constructor that hardcodes the class

Answer (score 0):

As @Mortsahl says, just do something like the following

```
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDAOImpl(){
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        type = (Class<T>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
```

This way you can extend out your generic DAO and still be eligible for autowiring.